Among all triangular pyramids that share vertices with a cube, how many have at least one face on a face of the cube?

Consider a cube and all the triangular pyramids having the vertices of the cube as vertices of the pyramids. How many of these pyramids have at least one face on a face of the cube?

My idea: Using the 8 vertices of the cube, we form groups of 4 vertices. We will have 70 groups.
Among these, the pyramids ABCD, EFGH, BCGF, ADHE, ABFE, CDHG, ABGH, CDEF, AEFC, DHFB, ADGF, EHCB, FDEB, GAHC, HDBG, CEFA, AHFC, BDEG do not satisfy the dimensional requirement.
Therefore, there remain 70 - 18 = 52  pyramids that are correct.

You need to specify how the edges of your cube are labelled.  If it were the same as in Pranay's answer, for instance, then AEFC would be a perfectly good pyramid which shares its face AEF  with the face AEFB of the cube.  But you have listed that as  not satisfying the dimensional requirements.

I think the answer is $56$. Let us count them based on how many faces they share with the faces of the cube.

Three faces: there are $8$ such tetrahedrons, one at each vertex of the cube. Here shown for vertex $A$.



Two faces: there are $2 \times 12 = 24$ such tetrahedrons, two per edge of the cube. Here shown for edge $AE$.

 

One face: there are $4\times 6 = 24$ such tetrahedrons, four per face of the cube. Here shown for face $ABCD$.

   
